# simultaneous Tkinter and Shell commands

Tags: python, shell, tkinter, simultaneous

I have made a programm with some simple Tkinter windows, for example a 'Hello' label. Is it possible to type and give commands in Python Shell simultaneously? I tried but Python Shell doesn't appear '>>>' to give commands,so when i type and press Enter , the cursor goes to the next line,instead of running the string. I hope you get my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to see the open window and simultaniously execute commands behind `>>>`.

Two solutions I see:

1. remove `xxx.mainloop()` when you execute it with the Python Shell. I did it like this conditionally.

   ```
   import sys
   if 'idlelib' not in sys.modules:
        xxx.mainloop()
   ```
2. start the mainloop in another thread. You should not do this in production code because Tkinter is not threadsafe.

   ```
    import threading
    t = threading.Thread(target = xxx.mainloop)
    t.start()
   ```

These are two solution I could think of because `1.` may not always work.